# Выборка данных из таблицы за определенный год

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Есть такая таблица в базе, тип базы MS SQL

```
id int identity PK
work_week int
holiday datetime -дата выходного дня
holiday_type
creation_date datetime
correction_date datetime NULL
user_id int
```

Как я могу произвести выборку данных из таблицы за определенный год по полю holiday

Вот пример моего класса entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "holidays")
public class Holiday {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "work_week", nullable = false)
private Integer workWeek;

@Column(name = "holiday", nullable = false)
private Instant holiday;

@Convert(converter = DayTypeConverter.class)
@Column(name = "holiday_type", nullable = false)
private DayType holidayType;

@Column(name = "creation_date", nullable = false)
private Instant creationDate;

@Column(name = "correction_date")
private Instant correctionDate;

@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Integer userId;
```

}

Использую стандартный spring data jpa
Пример класса repository
Я не совсем понимаю какой в него нужно добавить метод

```
@Repository
public interface HolidayRepository extends JpaRepository<Holiday, Integer> {

}
```

Опыт работы с JPA совсем небольшой, прошу помощи

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен что правильно написал, но вроде примерто так должно работать

```
public interface HolidayRepository extends JpaRepository<Holiday, Integer> {
    List<Holiday> findByHolidayBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
}
```

Либо так

```
public interface HolidayRepository extends JpaRepository<Holiday, Integer> {

    @Query("from Holiday where holiday > :startDate and holiday < :endDate")
    List<Holiday> findByHolidayBetween(@Param("startDate") Date startDate,
                                       @Param("endDate")  Date endDate);
}
```

Это примеры по дате, если хочешь именно за год то можешь использовать функцию mysql **YEAR(date)** которая возвращает год из даты, и сравнивать уже с переданными параметрами или параметром.
Примерно так:

```
public interface HolidayRepository extends JpaRepository<Holiday, Integer> {

    @Query("from Holiday where YEAR(holiday) = :year")
    List<Holiday> findByYear(@Param("year") Integer year);
}
```

Кстати @Repository не обязательная для репозиториев спринга, он сам знает где репозиторий.

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Comment: @ДмитрийРудов тогда примите ответ, если вы решили использовать этот ответ для решения вашей проблемы, на этом сайте так заведено )